# Django group by multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to transform this SQL request into a Django view:

```
SELECT color, shape, eyes, count(1) FROM animals WHERE master_id = 1 GROUP BY color, shape, eyes
```

In order to do that I've tried:

```
animals = Animals.objects.filter(id=1).values('color', 'shape', 'eyes').annotate(ct=Count('color'), dg=Count('shape'), br=Count('eyes'))
```

And then loop on the result to find the count for each one (not very optimized) and the result isn't good. That's group by as I want but doesn't care about the id.

EDIT:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'color': brown, 'shape': blabla, 'eyes': toto, 'ct': 2 },
    { 'color': black, 'shape': blabla, 'eyes': toto, 'ct': 1 },
    { 'color': yellow, 'shape': xxxxx, 'eyes': ok, 'ct': 4 }
]>
```

SECOND EDIT:

If I try that:

```
Animals.objects.filter(
    master_id=1
).values('color', 'shape', 'eyes').annotate(
    ct=Count('id')
).order_by('color', 'shape', 'eyes')
```

I have this result without count:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'color': brown, 'shape': blabla, 'eyes': toto},
    { 'color': black, 'shape': blabla, 'eyes': toto},
    { 'color': yellow, 'shape': xxxxx, 'eyes': ok }
]>
```

LAST EDIT:

The Animal table doesn't have count or ct column but I need it in my result

Comment: But here you will group per *configuration* of `cat, dog, bird`, so you do not count the number of `birds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete equivalent query would be:

```
Animals.objects.filter(
    master_id=1
).values('color', 'shape', 'eyes').annotate(
    ct=Count('id')
).order_by('color', 'shape', 'eyes')
```

This will then result in a `QuerySet` that wraps dictionaries, for example:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'color': 0, 'shape': 2, 'eyes': 1, 'ct': 1 },
    { 'color': 0, 'shape': 3, 'eyes': 3, 'ct': 4 },
    { 'color': 1, 'shape': 0, 'eyes': 0, 'ct': 2 },
    { 'color': 2, 'shape': 2, 'eyes': 1, 'ct': 5 },
]>
```

For example:

```
>>> Animals.objects.create(color='foo', shape='bar', eyes='brown', master_id=1)
<Animal: Animal object (2)>
>>> Animals.objects.create(color='foo', shape='bar', eyes='brown', master_id=1)
<Animal: Animal object (3)>
>>> Animals.objects.create(color='foo', shape='bar', eyes='blue', master_id=1)
<Animal: Animal object (4)>
>>> Animals.objects.create(color='foo', shape='rectangle', eyes='brown', master_id=1)
<Animal: Animal object (5)>
>>> Animals.objects.create(color='red', shape='rectangle', eyes='brown', master_id=1)
<Animal: Animal object (6)>
>>> Animals.objects.filter(
...     master_id=1
... ).values('color', 'shape', 'eyes').annotate(
...     ct=Count('id')
... ).order_by('color', 'shape', 'eyes')
<QuerySet [{'color': 'foo', 'shape': 'bar', 'eyes': 'blue', 'ct': 1}, {'color': 'foo', 'shape': 'bar', 'eyes': 'brown', 'ct': 2}, {'color': 'foo', 'shape': 'rectangle', 'eyes': 'brown', 'ct': 1}, {'color': 'red', 'shape': 'rectangle', 'eyes': 'brown', 'ct': 1}]>
```

Comment: thans for your answer @Willem but I don't have the count in my result. I should have ct:3 for the first line, ct:6 for the second etc. I will edit my question

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn: did you run the query in the database? If I ask Django to generate the SQL query, the two are (near) equivalent, except that there is an `ORDER BY` clause added.

Comment: I've edited my question, thanks for your help. The query you gave doesn't give me the count for each line

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn: except for changing the `.values(..)` **and** `.order_by(..)` (it is important to order, since otherwise the queryset is *not* "folded"), this should work. Also note that you should filter on the `master_id`, not the `id`.

Comment: it's a mistake in my question, I do the filter on master_id. But unfortunately the query doesn't works, I haven't the count in it

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn: can you share the result you *get* (not want), edit the quesiton.

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn: locally I get a dictionary with `ct`. Does your `Animal` model by any change contains a column `ct`?

Comment: If I run this locally, I get dictionaries with `'ct'`. Did you swap the `.values(..)` and `.annotate(..)` part? You can not just swap the Django ORM function calls in the chain.

Comment: No the Animal table doesn't have a 'ct' field but I want it in my result. Last edit on my question, sorry..

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn: well I can not reproduce your problem locally. If I however *swap* the `.values(..)` and `.annotate(..)` (so `Animal.objects.annotate(..).values(..)` then indeed the `ct` element is not in the dictionaries, but this is expected behavior: `.values(..)` should be called *before* the `.annotate(..)`.

Comment: I've tried both and never the count of each appear on the result

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn: what Django version are you using? I tried with 1.11, 2.0 and 2.1 and these all worked (see sample session in the answer).